# What's the deal with a dozen users removed yesterday?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts

I don't care much about rep and users do delete their accounts all the time, but this struck me as a bit unusual. I don't recall ever seeing this many users deleted in one day.

[image]

Did I have a sockpuppet fan club, or something like that, if it's publicly discussible? I haven't been active on site much, so possibly I've missed some announcements.

Comment: I’m closing this question because disciplinary matters of individual users who didn't explicitly asked for the matter to be handled publicly are confidential.

Comment: @Philipp Technically speaking, by [posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391481/what-happened-to-my-account-what-am-i-suspended-for?noredirect=1&lq=1) on [the global meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391531/why-was-i-suspended-an-explanation-would-be-good?noredirect=1&lq=1) about it [multiple times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391756/arent-voting-badges-counterproductive), they've effectively consented to having it in public.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the help of the Stack Exchange community team we recently discovered a ring of sock puppet accounts engaging in vote manipulation across several stack exchange sites.

Unfortunately I can not go into any more details.