# Why do users keep getting removed?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I must have lost more than 400 karma from all the users being removed from the site. Am I the only one? I find it weird that so many users are being removed. We should at least show the names of the users that are getting removed so we can see if they had a good reason to be removed.

Comment: No, we absolutely should not be breaching user privacy because you are concerned about a few arbitrary internet points. If you believe moderators have abused their responsible position, you report it to CMs.

Comment: At one point https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6579/whats-the-deal-with-a-dozen-users-removed-yesterday Actually, I did lose 80 rep yesterday to a "user removed". Almost didn't notice. But there was just one user removed yesterday, unlike in that prior mass event. One user being removed is not at all unusual.

Comment: "We should at least show the names of the users that are getting removed" - that's probably not possible, because... you know... *they've been removed*. Stack Exchange literally does not have that data anymore. If they did, they'd probably be violating GDPR. "so we can see if they had a good reason to be removed" - how do you intend to verify such a thing? Things like sock-puppeting and voting rings are only visible to moderators or staff.

Comment: This also assumes that none of those account deletions were [self-deletions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83453/have-any-israeli-leaders-condemned-calls-for-genocide-and-expulsion/83461?noredirect=1#comment366908_83461), which don't *need* a reason.

Comment: @Nij, would the CM actually take any relevant action, or just confirm a stitch-up?

Comment: Depends on how paranoid you are. Trust that they'll do the job properly or don't,  up to you, but if you're that unsure of the company's people responsible for community management, it must be a serious question, why remain in that community?

Answer (score 7):

Users are getting removed many reasons such as.

- Deleting their account
- Violating the rules on this site and their account is deleted
- violating the rules on other sites and their network account is deleted

None of this is ever revealed for privacy reasons.

Comment: If i delete my account tomorrow, will everyone lose the upvotes I have given them? That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @sfxedit That is how it works when a user is deleted for any reason all votes they cast are also removed meaning people lose or gain reputation based on how the votes got cast. There are a few meta questions on it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328642/massive-user-removal-in-one-night https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328673/always-preserve-votes-from-users-who-are-voluntarily-removed

Comment: I would like to add to this answer that we moderators usually don't delete well-established accounts, not matter what they do. We suspend them. We only delete accounts when they were created to post spam or if they were created to evade a suspension. But we have no control over what people do themselves. It happens occasionally that people choose to self-delete their accounts after getting suspended.

Comment: @sfxedit When an account is deleted, the votes the account cast may or may not be removed, which has been the case since 2015. Please see [answer to: "Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/271271) for an explanation as to how it works.