# Why did I lose 314 points from 7 users who got removed?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Why did I lose 314 points from 7 users who got removed today? I just lost 314 points from 7 users who got removed. I think it would be nice to have some transparency and know why sometimes a lot of users get removed like that all at once.

Comment: This is explained in the help page isn't it? https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed

Comment: Don't forget though that "legitimate post history" is a curated thing (you see only what is not deleted, most of the time), and it may have been a self-requested account deletion.

Comment: I don't think so since there were 8 accounts deleted at the same time and most of the anti-Israel questions got deleted, and not just closed, which is really weird. The moderation team needs to be more transparent about these things.

Comment: @Sayaman there may be a discussion to be had about the even-handedness of how toxic pro-Israel posts vs toxic pro-Palestine posts get treated by the moderators (I am sure glad I don't have to adjucate that mess ;-).  But that's not all that relevant to this question however.  Somebody either removed their account or got their account deleted.  No one went out to "bag" your points.  And you've asked this Q before https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6686/why-do-users-keep-getting-removed so it a self-duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do users keep getting removed?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6686/why-do-users-keep-getting-removed)

Comment: it keeps happening, i lost 40 points just now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately we moderators don't have any tools that show us more information on which user deletions exactly lead to that loss in reputation for you in particular. But I have an idea what could have happened.

Accounts that are well-established on this site usually don't get outright deleted by us, no matter what they do. When they misbehave, then they usually get suspended. While an account is suspended, their votes on other people's posts remain.

We mods only delete accounts when they are brand-new accounts that were created to evade suspensions or post spam. And it just so happens that there is a certain long-term network-wide suspended person I am not going to name who lately created a lot of sock puppet accounts. These accounts were upvoting each other and also upvoted random other posts, presumably to obfuscate their voting ring activity. 9 hours ago, we deleted 11 such accounts. Which, by the way, was coordinated with the Stack Exchange Community Management team. It appears that you were one of those users they used to spread their votes.

Comment: Yup.  Even recurring "problem" accounts tend to stick around - hopping from one one-year to another.  They don't seem to get deleted much.  I've seen 2 year bans tho and one ends in 2**1**23.

Comment: how many sockpuppet accounts does he have, because i got 2 other mentions of users getting removed?

Comment: just one suggestion if the upvote was made like 2-3 years ago, i don't think they should get reverted, the user with the sockpuppet accounts should just get banned, because i feel like a lot of long time users may lose 500+ reputation point from one user sockpuppeting.

Comment: @Sayaman: most of those socks upvoted at least one Q of mine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLJsO.png